# When to use Partial view in ASP MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that has 4 hidden `div`s, there are 4 buttons to bring up the Corresponding `div`s.
Instead of writing all the code on one page, I have split it into partial views (so that the `div`s are in partial views) 
E.g.

```
<div class="hide" id="Doctor">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Medical/_Doctor.cshtml")
</div>
```

It feels wrong for some reason to do it like this, doesn't it?

Comment: its up to you how you use them. If the contents of the partial views will be repeated on several other pages then that can save repetition of code. It the partials will only be used on the 1 page, there is no real point in using a partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why this would be "wrong".  If it helps reduce the complexity of your code, then it helps.

Partials are typically used for the following reasons (but not strictly):

1. For child actions and ajax requests
2. For reuse of common code
3. To simplify complex pages

The thing to watch out for is that if you pass an object to a partial as it's model, it may not render any form fields in the correct manner to be properly bound on postback.  This is what EditorTemplates are for, although if you know what you're doing you can also make Partials work for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK.

Partial Views are great feature and don't be afraid to use it. 
Maybe it seems like additional fuss and complications at the start, but code with Partial Views is easier to maintain.

And finally, if you want to refresh only one part of your screen, Partial View is a way to go.